Show all non-published Staging Ground questions in tagged questions page
Currently only new Staging Ground questions are shown on tagged questions page.
That means significantly lower visibility of SG questions that have some other status. Lower visibility means that such questions mainly depend on feedback from the few people who already reviewed those questions. This can be especially problematic for questions that need re-evaluation as original reviewers might no longer be in the best position to judge the question.
For instance, you don't have to be an expert to see that some question is completely lacking minimal reproducible example, but when one is added you might not be able to judge whether the provided example is adequate.
Many curators and experts, especially in low traffic tags, use the tagged questions page to curate posts. Hiding Staging Ground questions that have already received some feedback in those tags is even more damaging. Not everyone will go to the Staging Ground queue and look for questions there.
Please show all unpublished SG questions in the tagged questions page and allow us to use the curating workflow we are already used to.

I think questions in "Major Changes"/"Minor Edits"/"Duplicate"/"Off-topic" are irrelevant in this regard and only questions in the "New" and "Re-Evaluate" states need to be reviewed normally.

Also when looking into the list of posts in Re-Evaluate, it seems there aren't many posts in that state and the least recent "last activity" is yesterday.

@dan1st personally I don't mind those states being shown in the question listing as well. With respect to the question listing, SG questions are similar to closed questions. Given we don't hide closed questions in the listing why hide SG questions (to be more specific why hide SG questions in certain states)?

@dan1st other states can also be relevant as their reviewers could made a mistake. Additionally, for some questions there may be just enough information in them that some expert could recognize the problem and fix the question to be publishable. When it comes to minor edits, again there are other users who can do such polishing changes and there is no need to hold on publishing such posts that can be fixed by others.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I think showing these questions (which shouldn't need review) would reduce the visibility of questions actually needing review (there's only so much space for (SG) questions in the question list). There are significantly more questions in non-review states than questions requiring review (New/Re-Evaluate).

If a question in another state should be moved, the author should edit it, make any necessary clarification and request Re-Evaluation moving it to "Re-Evaluate". The UI should make that clear to askers (I agree that there are some cases where this isn't really done but I think it's better to improve the asker UI for that).

@dan1st personally I dislike the "place SG questions in specific spots in the question list" strategy being used currently. IMO it would be much better if SG questions were sorted like normal questions. Some users might complain about there being too many SG questions but they can disable showing SG questions if they want to. The point of showing those questions there is to get more SMEs to review if the questions being shown to them are limited like that it's obvious that number won't go up much. If SG questions are sorted normally ones that need review will come up in the active tab.

@dan1st for questions that need review, there is always a SG review queue. If we want SG to be successful, then question should not be stuck there for a long periods of time, or never properly reevaluated. The more eyes are on those questions the more feedback they can receive. sometimes the feedback is too generic because reviewers are not SME, with more SME involved feedback could be more tailored to the actual problem.

@AbdulAzizBarkat If you can think of a better strategy of including Staging Ground questions in the question lists, feel free to create a distinct [feature-request] for that. I do think it isn't ideal but I don't know a better way to do it and IMO this is outside of the scope of this post.

@DalijaPrasnikar Currently, the main purpose (as far as I am concerned) of including SG questions in the question pages is to get more people to review these questions and I do think this is necessary. It am not opposed to including questions in other states if there are no New/Re-Evaluate questions but I don't think we want questions in "needs review" states to "starve" as the /staging-ground page and "review queue mode" are probably not sufficient to review questions in these states. Also, most questions in non-"needs review" states probably don't need any attention.

@dan1st Those new questions will not starve if there are other questions in the list, as they will commonly be more recently listed. I have also seen plenty of questions in needs "major changes" status that were basically dead in the water as the feedback was too generic and OP didn't know what else to do and how to address the problem.

There are situations where user posts exactly the same question as in SG (with minor changes) that ends up on the main site directly and that question gets appropriate comments and gets polished and answered. Without being seen SG becomes a place where questions go to die.

If the feedback is too generic, the author can still re-evaluate the question and explain that in the comments. I just think that most questions in non-"needs review" states don't need any action from other users since that's what these states are designed for. And are you sure the question list prefers more recent Staging Ground posts?

@dan1st They are all sorted by time, so most recent ones will be first.

Are you talking about the Staging Ground posts included in the tagged questions pages? As far as I know, these are randomly selected to be put into fixed positions and ignore the sorting of the other questions.

@dan1st You are right, they have been inserted randomly. I was looking previous order in Delphi tag, and there is not much traffic there, so it looked like all were sorted by time.

Anyway, I don't mind if ones that are not reviewed at all have different sort, but there is no reason why others couldn't be inserted by time. In low traffic tags there is usually few days worth of questions on the first page.

See Why are Staging Ground questions not sorted correctly with the Newest / Active sorting option? (and the dupe target) for random insertions. It randomly picks a SG question matching the tag.

(1) Can you clarify exactly which SG page you are referring to? I see plenty of "major changes" status questions in the SG where I'm reviewing. (2) SG wasn't intended for SMEs to be the primary reviewers. Ideally anyone with enough SO experience can identify poor quality posts and "coach" authors. (3) I see no problem with posts getting stuck in SG if the authors can't be bothered enough to listen to the feedback being provided to them and make any improvements to their posts to get them to a publishable state.

@DrewReese I am talking about tagged questions page. Where all regular questions related to a tag are visible and where also SG questions with status "New" appear. But once the status of that question is changed to something else it disappears from tagged questions page. While we don't rely on SME to do anything, SME are in the best position to provide the best feedback on any post.

Ohhhhh, I see. Eh, yeah I think I wouldn't mind having more SG questions mixed in there that needed review (seeing the one is usually a cue that I need to swap hats and go SG review for a bit), but as for questions that have already been reviewed I wouldn't want them cluttering up the page/list. Perhaps the feature request should add query/filter parameters so reviewers can customize their feed. Is this what you mean by "use the curating workflow we are already used to"?

@dan1st I do commonly go through the "major changes" questions to see if I can offer more precise feedback about the needed changes. And a fair amount of the time, I realize that although the question wouldn't be good enough to stand on its own, it's good enough to recognize as a duplicate.

@KarlKnechtel What do you mean with recognizing them as duplicates? There's not really a point for adding them to question lists for doing that because non-reviewers can't see these questions anyways.

I mean that rather than wait for OP to polish a question that, if properly asked, would be closed as a duplicate on the main site directly, I vote as duplicate so that they see the canonical right away.

If anyone can find a duplicate target for a question, it can be marked as such (in the Staging Ground) provided a reviewer can find a duplicate target but I don't feel like there's much of a point/benefit in searching duplicates for questions in "Major Changes" as opposed to just doing the same for questions in "New"/"Re-Evaluate". And for people who want to look at questions in "Major Changes", the /staging-ground page should be more than enough.

@DrewReese Yes. I am usually doing most of curating through tagged questions page and I would want to see other questions from SG that were already reviewed, but are not yet published.

by "tagged question page", do you mean the SG page with filters applied? or a custom tag filter page? or something else?

@starball Regular questions list page which you see when you click on some tag, outside of the SG.

My 2cts, but since the beginning of the SG, I don't really find that (most) SME's and knowledgeable Users following a specific Tag are doing "much good" for the SG-process: First, (first 4-6 weeks) they were often already starting to answer Qt's in the SG already, upon which Askers would directly stop responding/reacting to other Reviewers trying to improve their Qt. Now, (last 4-6 weeks), I observe an opposite trend where the same knowledgeable Users put the bar too high, and keep Qt's in Major Changes, asking for some obscure Log, while those Qt's have already reached a decent Quality...

@chivracq We need more training and that also means people need to be exposed to SG questions. Having more eyes on all stages, makes it easier to correct and learn.

I agree that it might make sense to come up with better "expected quality standards"/what is expected from reviewers and maybe make sure that every Staging Ground reviewer (even those that reviewed questions in the past) see that as part of some onboarding but I don't know whether onboarding like that would be implemented.

Yes, "Onboarding" is (still) the word, several Threads about that in the last 3 months, and yep indeed, like @dan1st says, that "even those that reviewed questions in the past" see it (again), especially when anything in the guidelines changes... Some direct link at the bottom of the 'SG Stats Widget' could be useful maybe, and with a "New" or "Updated" in red when stg has changed...

I think there was the idea of some interactive onboarding process at some point but We need Staging Ground reviewer onboarding before showing it in the question list is all we got until now.

Yep, that was the Thread I had in mind..., but not only showing "before", because for most knowledgeable Users following a Tag, it's already long too late...

I actually like/prefer the separations of concerns between the Staging Ground being a completely separate area of the site away from the normal Questions page. I would find it difficult to switch between "SG quality review" mode and the normal "debug/vote/answer" mode of the question pages. Seeing a new, un-reviewed SG post in the questions is typically my cue to switch modes and actually go do SG reviews for a bit, with a completely different mindset, goal, and focus.
That said, I don't see much harm in including all SG posts in with the regular questions so long as they:

Maintain the same timeline order and the published posts
Are configurable/filterable in much the same way as regular questions, or toggleable via profile settings.

I'd prefer this to be more of an "opt-in" feature, where users would need to manually edit their views to include SG content with search results as SG quality-control is parallel to (a) searching for answers to my questions, and (b) searching for questions I can answer. I understand this hurts discoverability, so the Search Help page should be updated to include how to search/filter/include SG posts.

When you say "search results" do you also mean those where there is just a tag in search or just all other searches? What I would like to have is that click on tag which leads to tagged questions page also shows all SG questions, and that this visibility could be changed through user settings. If I would have to type into search box some additional text to show them that would defat the simplicity of workflow and purpose of showing all SG questions to more people.

@DalijaPrasnikar Yes, here "search results" is the list of questions for whatever search criteria has, or has not, been entered in the box, be it a single tag, multiple tags, tags + query params, nothing, etc. I don't wish for the default question/answer view to have SG posts included, I'd prefer the extra few keystrokes/clicks to have them included. You can save your search to load later. It's my preference SG content be discoverable in the SG area.

I am visiting many tags (although I am not doing the same actions in all of them), adding few keystrokes is a showstopper. I cannot save them all. I don't want to push SG questions on everyone, but I would like that those preferences could be set for user in our profile settings page. Just like there is now "Show Staging Ground questions" switch, another one could be added to show all non-published SG questions or not. Nothing less, nothing more.

Note that for the search, you can use the staging-ground:all/yes/no operator and whatever filters you like (but you cannot filter by SG state, that's only possible in /staging-ground).

@dan1st Ah, son of a gun, they did add a section all the way at the end/bottom of the search help page for that staging-ground operator. Could use a bit of clarity though.

@dan1st that operator only works partially as you say though, there's no staging-ground:all or staging-ground:no operator only a staging-ground:yes.

My fault, I remembered that incorrectly.
